# Code inserted triplicate records a few times and now works periodically

Tags: php, foreach

I have code that inserts a row in the points table when a user1 approves a post. I wrote code so that it only approves the post if the user is not the author of the post. There can be a maximum of 10 posts at any time to choose from for approve.

However, while this will only approve a post (and insert a record in points) if the current user is not the author of the post, it will not just insert the record for the post that is approved. Rather it will insert as many rows into points table as there are posts for user.

What I want to do is insert into points for a post that is approved by the current user where the post author is not the current user.

I am very close. This code works, except that it will insert all records if there are multiple posts by other users instead of just the one post that the current user chooses to approve.

```
$results2 = $dbh->prepare("select 
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
stories.ID AS ID1,
stories.SID,
writing.ID AS ID2,
writing.WID,
writing.text
FROM writing
LEFT JOIN stories on writing.SID = stories.SID
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON writing.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE (stories.SID = $the_SID)
order by writing.WID asc limit 10
");

$results2->bindParam(':wp_users.ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$results2->bindParam(':display_name', $display_name, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$results2->bindParam(':stories.ID', $ID1, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$results2->bindParam(':stories.SID', $the_SID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$results2->bindParam(':writing.WID', $WID, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$results2->bindParam(':writing.ID', $ID2, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$results2->bindParam(':text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$results2->execute();
$row2 = $results2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row2 as $result5) {
     $blurb = $result5['ID2'];
     settype($blurb, "integer");
}




//PA APPROVE INSERT CONTROL

if(isset($_POST ['yes'])){

// Get values from form 
$yes_WID = $_POST['yes'];

$yesupdate = "UPDATE writing SET approved = :approved, position = :position   
WHERE WID = :WID";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate);
$stmt2->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt2->bindParam(':approved', $e = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt2->bindParam(':position', $row2[0]['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                        
$stmt2->execute();




$yes_WID = $_POST['yes'];

//trying to give points as long as user is not the author

$contpoint = 3;
foreach($row2 as $result5){
     if($blurb !== $user_ID){

          $yesupdate2 = "INSERT INTO points(ID, 
          SID,
          WID,
          PID) VALUES(
          :ID,
          :SID,
          :WID,
          :PID)";
          $stmt9 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate2);
          $stmt9->bindParam(':ID', $blurb, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
          $stmt9->bindParam(':SID', $the_SID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
          $stmt9->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
          $stmt9->bindParam(':PID', $contpoint, PDO::PARAM_INT);     
          $stmt9->execute();

     }
}
```

Comment: can you edit your question? How you obtain $blurb?

Comment: First it would help if you would use better naming, if there are "blurbs" with "authors" call the variable holding the name of one blurb author `$blurbAuthor` not `blurb`.   From your second comment it looks like `blub` is an array of authors one for each item, is that correct? I think in that case `$blub` is never going to equal $user_ID which I assume is an integer.  What is `result6` user for?

Comment: Could your code be running on a server in which at least three users are logged into the exact same account?

Comment: @Elin I have edited my post to show the sql where I get the list of posts from all users. In the first foreach loop I get the ID of each author of each blurb which I then use for my second foreach loop lower down so that user1 can approve the give points to a user's post as long as the current user is not the author of that post. But again, it works sometimes. Other times it inserts identical 3 rows instead of just 1. Othertimes nothing at all.

Comment: I have articulated the issue better in my edited post. I think this code works except it will insert as many rows into points as there are posts. I need it to only insert a row for the post that is approved.

Comment: Perhaps a where clause in my insert query somehow? like where WHERE WID = :WID

Comment: Is the brace between the two code listings part of the first foreach loop?

Comment: @Reenactor Rob yes it is

Comment: $blurb is going to be equal to the last id.

Comment: @Elin Are you sure? The evaluation part of this seems to be working and I though the foreach would do the trick. how else would i capture the ID of each piece of writing to compare and be sure it is not the current user (user_ID)?

Comment: Do you think $blurb needs to become an array variable to store the value of each author for each piece of writing returned in $result5>  If I do foreach ($row2 as $result5) {
  $blurb = $result5['ID2'];
  echo var_dump($result5);
  echo $blurb;
}   I see that array of 9 variables for each story/blurb and the correct author ID shown for $blurb. But maybe each author should be an in an array for when I compare it to the user_ID later?

Comment: Yes it needs to be an array, if it is not an array there is only one value, the last one. The alternative is to move that to inside the second `foreach`  so you are running though each of the ids instead of just the last one.

Comment: This is extremely ugly but you could just wrap the firs `foreach` around the second one so that `$blub` has a vlaue. But for the love of all that is good please change the variable name to `$blurbAuthor` if blub is what you are calling the whole row. Using clear names will make it much easier to understand your code. So will indenting.

Comment: @Elin Tried to wrap by putting ending } of first foreach after }} of last foreach. That just kept making the page flicker and refresh over and over.  Then I tried moving the first foreach directly above the second and nothing happens to the db at all

Comment: Amazingly I figured this out. The only thing was to simply do if($blurbauthor != $user_ID) {   before the $yesupdate. There was no need for a second loop. That second loop was causing the multiple inserts.

Comment: The problem is that you need to have a different value of $blurb for each it `if($blurb !== $user_ID)` is evaluated. That is currently you have 1 value that is always used.   Most likely you would want to have a different value of $blurb for each $result5.  What are you even using $results5 for, I don't see it inside the loop at all?  most likely you want to test if  `$result5['ID2'] != $user_ID` for each row.  Why are you calling that $result5? Why not just call it $row so that it makes semantic sense?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your if condition is not being evaluated properly.  Are $blurb and $user_ID the same type?

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> $a != $b  Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
>
> $a !==$b    Not identical   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of
>   the same type.

Comment: same type as in both integers. They are. I tried this and the code is inserting the row with points regardless of who the author is. Even if the author of the post is the current user.

Comment: I would print out the values of the loop variables and the condition tests so that you can see what is happening in the comparisons.  Something is not what it appears to be.

Comment: perhaps your approach of !== is saying they are are the same type (integers) and so it evalutes true even if the user IDs are different. At least with != it properly evaluated as I needed until I logged in as user 2. I only have two users 1 and 2. $user_ID is 1 and i want to ignore the insert anytime the $blurb is 1.

Comment: Could it have to do with there being no "else" clause for the case where the if clause is not met?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this code?  It just sets $blurb to each of the values and then does nothing with the result unless the brace in between the code listings is not correctly shown.  So is it a foreach inside of a foreach?

In any case, it does not appear that you set $user_ID as an integer in the same manner as you do for $blurb.

```
foreach ($row2 as $result5) {
$blurb = $result5['ID2'];
settype($blurb, "integer");
}
```

Do away with the first foreach loop and combine it with the second as such:

```
foreach($row2 as $result5){
    $blurb = $result5['ID2'];
    $userID = $result5['user_ID'];
    settype($blurb, "integer");
    settype($userID, "integer");
if($blurb !== $userID){
   ...etc
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this a go. The only thing is there is a step in between I had left out of my post (just added it) where the approved story post is first added to the story/post table AND THEN the author of that post is awarded the points (the insert to the post table). If I put the foreach together, I'm not sure where/how to do that considering the $yesupdate UPDATE code that has to run as well.

Comment: Ok. But I think your problem with the if condition is that you reference user_ID incorrectly.

Comment: I didn't make user_ID part of the query. That is set in the very beginning of the code (Wordpress) with 
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

Comment: I don't think I am having any problems with evaluating the author ID vs the current user. The problem is with my insert code and how it will insert as many rows into points as there are blurbs by authors who are not the current user.

Comment: Amazingly I figured this out. The only thing was to simply do if($blurbauthor != $user_ID) {   before the $yesupdate. There was no need for a second loop. That second loop was causing the multiple inserts.