# Can I have a WHERE clause in an INSERT statement?

Tags: php

Is it possible to have a where clause in an insert statement? I can't find any documentation on this. I would like to do something like this:

```
$yesupdate2 = "INSERT INTO points(ID, 
SID,
WID,
PID) WHERE WID = :WID
VALUES(
:ID,
:SID,
:WID,
:PID)";
$stmt9 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate2);
$stmt9->bindParam(':ID', $blurb, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
$stmt9->bindParam(':SID', $the_SID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt9->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt9->bindParam(':PID', $contpoint, PDO::PARAM_INT);     
$stmt9->execute();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an insert statement you wouldn't have an existing row to do a where claues on? You are inserting a new row, did you mean to do an update statment?

```
update users set ID=$wblurb and WID=$yes_WID WHERE WID = $wid
```

Something like this would help..

Comment: you are right...just realized that is why it can't be done. But I can't use update because there are no records to update either. I am trying to insert a row in the points table awarding points for blog post when someone approves that post.

Comment: Simply add a column and keep on updating its value if someone approves it post...By default set it as 0 or null and when someone approves the post update the value..

Comment: you mean a column in the points table called score or something? I was going to do that, but there are different types of points for different types of things, so I need a unique record I think for each time points are awarded to a user such as when someone approves their blog

Comment: What you can do is to alter table and add column depending upon the how you want to add the points... add a simple `alter table` query...

Comment: true, but sadly this is more complex because the code needs to cycle through each post and know who is the author is for that post and compare to be sure it is not the current user. Then it has to insert or update the points for just that one piece of writing (and not all 10 showing). I have more detail about this same code at URL below:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734372/code-inserted-triplicate-records-a-few-times-and-now-works-periodically

Comment: did  any answer help...?

Comment: sadly no. this one is rather complicated.

Comment: Amazingly I figured this out! The only thing was to simply do if($blurbauthor != $user_ID) {   before the $yesupdate. There was no need for a second loop. That second loop was causing the multiple inserts.